# TSQL Grouping by time with Start and End dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, time, aggregation

I have been struggling to make a set of reports that gives the sum of calories burned in 15 minute increments for "Teams" and "Users.

The tables I am using are as follows:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('Teams') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE Teams;

CREATE TABLE Teams
(
Team_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
Team_Name varchar(100),
Team_Description varchar(200)
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('Users') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE Users;

CREATE TABLE Users
(
User_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
User_Name varchar(100)
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('Team_User') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE Team_User;

CREATE TABLE Team_User
(
Team_ID int,
User_ID int
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('Workouts') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE Workouts;

CREATE TABLE Workouts
(
Workout_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
User_ID int,
Workout_Type int,
Start_Time datetime,
End_Time datetime,
Calories float
);

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('LK_Workout_Type') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE LK_Workout_Type;

CREATE TABLE LK_Workout_Type
(
WT_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
Workout_Name varchar (80),
Workout_Description varchar(200)
);

INSERT INTO Teams (Team_Name, Team_Description) VALUES ('A Team', 'We are not vets.');
INSERT INTO Teams (Team_Name, Team_Description) VALUES ('Team Solo', 'One man. One team.');

INSERT INTO Users (User_Name) VALUES ('Frank Appleton');
INSERT INTO Users (User_Name) VALUES ('Tim Murdock');
INSERT INTO Users (User_Name) VALUES ('Tim Smith');

INSERT INTO Team_User (Team_ID, User_ID) Values (1,1);
INSERT INTO Team_User (Team_ID, User_ID) Values (1,2);
INSERT INTO Team_User (Team_ID, User_ID) Values (2,3);

INSERT INTO LK_Workout_Type (Workout_Name, Workout_Description) VALUES ('Bike - Mountain','Trail riding.');
INSERT INTO LK_Workout_Type (Workout_Name, Workout_Description) VALUES ('Bike - Road','Road riding.');
INSERT INTO LK_Workout_Type (Workout_Name, Workout_Description) VALUES ('Elliptical','Standard elliptical');
INSERT INTO LK_Workout_Type (Workout_Name, Workout_Description) VALUES ('Running','Typical running');
INSERT INTO LK_Workout_Type (Workout_Name, Workout_Description) VALUES ('Treadmill','Treadmill running');
INSERT INTO LK_Workout_Type (Workout_Name, Workout_Description) VALUES ('Weights','Weightroom');

INSERT INTO Workouts (User_ID, Workout_Type, Start_Time, End_Time, Calories) VALUES (1,1,'3/10/2012 08:00:00 AM','3/10/2012 09:30:00 AM', 860);
INSERT INTO Workouts (User_ID, Workout_Type, Start_Time, End_Time, Calories) VALUES (2,1,'3/10/2012 08:30:00 AM','3/10/2012 10:45:00 AM', 950);
INSERT INTO Workouts (User_ID, Workout_Type, Start_Time, End_Time, Calories) VALUES (3,5,'3/10/2012 10:05:00 AM','3/10/2012 12:27:00 PM', 1917);
INSERT INTO Workouts (User_ID, Workout_Type, Start_Time, End_Time, Calories) VALUES (1,5,'3/10/2012 02:38:00 PM','3/10/2012 03:17:00 PM', 536);
```

One of the reports I want to generate displays the calories burned by a given team, in specific increments and time frame. So, If I want to display the A-Team's calories burned from 8 AM to 6 PM on a given day in 15 minute increments, the report should look like this:
    TheDt         Team     Calories
    08:00:00 AM   A-Team   860
    08:15:00 AM   A-Team   860
    08:30:00 AM   A-Team   1810
    08:45:00 AM   A-Team   1810
    09:00:00 AM   A-Team   1810
    09:15:00 AM   A-Team   1810
    09:30:00 AM   A-Team   1810
    09:45:00 AM   A-Team   950
    10:00:00 AM   A-Team   950
    10:15:00 AM   A-Team   950
    10:30:00 AM   A-Team   950
    10:45:00 AM   A-Team   950
    11:00:00 AM   A-Team   0
    ....
    02:30:00 PM   A-Team   0
    02:45:00 PM   A-Team   536
    03:00:00 PM   A-Team   536
    03:15:00 PM   A-Team   536
    03:30:00 PM   A-Team   0
    ...
    06:00:00 PM  A-Team   0

In my research, I discovered that using a table to support the increments (15 mins) and joining it to my Workouts table should help. So, I created the following table:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('Tally') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE Tally;

CREATE TABLE Tally 
    (N INT, 
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tally_N PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N))

-----------Create and preset a loop counter
DECLARE @Counter INT
    SET @Counter = 0

-----------Populate the table with 15 minute intervals between 2012 and 2017
  WHILE @Counter <= 175299
  BEGIN
         INSERT INTO Tally (N) VALUES (@Counter) SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    END

-----------Build the CalendarDT Table
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('CalendarDT') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE CalendarDT;

DECLARE @StartDT DATETIME;

SELECT @StartDT = '2012-01-01T00:00:00';

SELECT  DATEADD(mi,v.N*15,@StartDT) AS TheDT INTO CalendarDT FROM Tally v WHERE v.N BETWEEN 0 AND 175299;

-----------Creating a clustered index for performance
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('IDXC_CalendarDT_TheDT') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsIndex') = 1)
DROP INDEX CalendarDT.IDXC_CalendarDT_TheDT;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDXC_CalendarDT_TheDT ON CalendarDT (TheDT)
GO

-----------Drop the Tally table
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('Tally') AND  OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsTable') = 1)
DROP TABLE Tally;
```

I then tried to join my Workouts table with the following:

```
SELECT  CalendarDT.TheDT AS [Date], COALESCE(SUM(Workouts.Calories),0) AS CalorieCnt, Workouts.User_ID
FROM    CalendarDT
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Workouts ON Workouts.Start_Time >= '03/10/2012 08:00:00 AM' AND Workouts.End_Time < '03/10/2012 06:00:00 PM'
        AND CalendarDT.TheDT >= '03/10/2012 08:00:00 AM' AND CalendarDT.TheDT <= '03/10/2012 06:00:00 PM'
WHERE   Workouts.User_ID IN (SELECT User_ID FROM Team_User WHERE Team_ID = 1)
GROUP BY CalendarDT.TheDT, Workouts.User_ID
ORDER BY CalendarDT.TheDT;
```

This is as close as I've been able to come to the solution. But, I have a few problems:

1) I haven't figured out how to join the Team_Name from within the JOIN statement.

2) The CalorieCnt, even if it was aggregated by Team_Name instead of User_ID shows the same values for each time period. It's not aggregating the totals properly for each given time, including those times when it should be 0.

I think one of the problems is that I can't get the comparison of how many calories were burnt at say 08:45:00 AM because there is no Workout that started/ended at that time. 
I've been looking at this for a while and I'm stumped. Any help getting these reports working for an individual user and by team would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The value in `calories` means "calories burnt in 15 minutes" or "calories burnt during the workout"?

Comment: Workouts.calories is the number of calories burnt during the workout.  The report is not as accurate as it could be since Workouts.calories is for the entire workout. And, the report generated is for 15 minute intervals. I realize this. But, that's the data I have to work with. And, does add value to the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH    ranges (st) AS
        (
        SELECT  CAST('2012-03-10 08:00:00' AS DATETIME)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(minute, 15, st)
        FROM    ranges
        WHERE   DATEADD(minute, 15, st) < CAST('2012-03-10 18:00:00' AS DATETIME)
        )
SELECT  st, team_name, calories
FROM    (
        SELECT  st, team_id, COALESCE(SUM(calories), 0) AS calories
        FROM    ranges r
        LEFT JOIN
                workouts w
        ON      start_time < DATEADD(minute, 15, st)
                AND end_time > st
        LEFT JOIN
                team_user tu
        ON      tu.user_id = w.user_id
        GROUP BY
                st, team_id
        ) c
LEFT JOIN
        teams t
ON      t.team_id = c.team_id
ORDER BY
        c.st, c.team_id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: That is really close! You have solved the joining of the Team_Name problem. And, the aggregation is correct when there are values. However, I want to be able to show those times in the range where the value of calories is 0.

Comment: @user1319487: of course, sorry, just replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` in the inner query.

Comment: Thanks for the Quassnoi...didn't quite work that way. But, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi. It does work now. It is slightly different than the CROSS JOIN solution provided by Steve. They both have the pro's and cons. What I like about Steve's solution is that it's easier to see the combination of times and teams where no calories were burned. In your solution it is implied. So, it will take a little bit more work on my part do display that properly. However, I think the CROSS JOIN solution can lead to problems if I need to change the structure of the tables.

Comment: Also, as your solution returns less rows, it should be more robust w/out other changes as more and more workouts are added. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.  I modified the CTE from the example above to get all the teams for all of the ranges even when calories is 0.

```
WITH    ranges_CTE (st) AS
(
   SELECT  CAST('2012-03-10 08:00:00' AS DATETIME)
    UNION ALL
   SELECT  DATEADD(minute, 15, st)
     FROM    ranges_CTE
    WHERE   DATEADD(minute, 15, st) < CAST('2012-03-10 18:00:00' AS DATETIME)
),
team_CTE (team_name, team_id) AS
(
SELECT team_name, team_id 
  FROM teams
),
ranges_team_CTE (st, team_name, team_id) AS
(
   SELECT r.st, t.team_name, t.team_id
 FROM ranges_CTE as r
CROSS JOIN team_CTE as t
)
select t.st, t.team_name, isnull(c.calories, '')
  from ranges_team_cte t
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  st, team_id, COALESCE(SUM(calories), 0) AS calories
    FROM    ranges_CTE r
    LEFT JOIN
            workouts w
    ON      start_time < DATEADD(minute, 15, st)
            AND end_time > st
    LEFT JOIN    team_user tu
    ON      tu.user_id = w.user_id
    GROUP BY
            st, team_id
    ) c ON t.team_id = c.team_id AND t.st = c.st
ORDER BY
    t.st, t.team_id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Which produces these output.  If I understand what you are looking for I think that this gives you what you want.

```
st                      team_name            calories
----------------------- -------------------- ----------------------
2012-03-10 08:00:00.000 A Team               860
2012-03-10 08:00:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 08:15:00.000 A Team               860
2012-03-10 08:15:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 08:30:00.000 A Team               1810
2012-03-10 08:30:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 08:45:00.000 A Team               1810
2012-03-10 08:45:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 09:00:00.000 A Team               1810
2012-03-10 09:00:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 09:15:00.000 A Team               1810
2012-03-10 09:15:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 09:30:00.000 A Team               950
2012-03-10 09:30:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 09:45:00.000 A Team               950
2012-03-10 09:45:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 10:00:00.000 A Team               950
2012-03-10 10:00:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 10:15:00.000 A Team               950
2012-03-10 10:15:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 10:30:00.000 A Team               950
2012-03-10 10:30:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 10:45:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 10:45:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 11:00:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 11:00:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 11:15:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 11:15:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 11:30:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 11:30:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 11:45:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 11:45:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 12:00:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 12:00:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 12:15:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 12:15:00.000 Team Solo            1917
2012-03-10 12:30:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 12:30:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 12:45:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 12:45:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 13:00:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 13:00:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 13:15:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 13:15:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 13:30:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 13:30:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 13:45:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 13:45:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 14:00:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 14:00:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 14:15:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 14:15:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 14:30:00.000 A Team               536
2012-03-10 14:30:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 14:45:00.000 A Team               536
2012-03-10 14:45:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 15:00:00.000 A Team               536
2012-03-10 15:00:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 15:15:00.000 A Team               536
2012-03-10 15:15:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 15:30:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 15:30:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 15:45:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 15:45:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 16:00:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 16:00:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 16:15:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 16:15:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 16:30:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 16:30:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 16:45:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 16:45:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 17:00:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 17:00:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 17:15:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 17:15:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 17:30:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 17:30:00.000 Team Solo            0
2012-03-10 17:45:00.000 A Team               0
2012-03-10 17:45:00.000 Team Solo            0
(80 row(s) affected)
```

Is this what you are looking for?